# What is the mistake in this quicksort implementation?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, debugging, quicksort

The code works for a few test cases but fails for most. Where am I getting it wrong?

Also if anything could be done to make the code more efficient.

```
void quicksort(int *a, int a1, int b1)
{
if ((b1 - a1) > 0)
{
    int pivot = (a1 + b1) / 2;
    int i = a1;
    int j = b1;
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (a[i] < a[pivot]) //left to right
            i++;
        while (a[j] > a[pivot]) //right to left
            j--;
        if (i < j) // swapping
        {
            int temp;
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }

    }
    quicksort(a, a1, j);
    quicksort(a, i, b1); //recursive calls
}
```

}

Comment: this is just not quicksort.  You are not moving the pivot value.

Comment: actually, nevermind  I think this looks correct.  What inputs are getting wrong results?

Comment: a = {2 45 56 3 125} is one of those. The program just hangs. I don't see how it can get caught up in the while loop.

Comment: well, consider what happens if you call it with just [1, 2]

Comment: there are 2 problems here.  One with the condition and the other that your pivot value is tied to the position in the array which is wrong.  pivot value is value, not position.

Comment: Array a = [1, 2] implies I will be passing quicksort(a, 0, 1) /*0,1 are indices of extremities*/; b1-a1 condition is satisfied; pivot = 1; i =0; b=1; since 0<=1, i evaluates to 1, j evaluates to 0, but since 1<0 is false, they dont get swapped; quicksort(a,0,0) and quicksort(a,1,1) are called which don't get evaluated. Any mistakes in this logic?

Comment: Array a = [1, 2] implies I will be passing quicksort(a, 0, 1) /*0,1 are indices of extremities*/; b1-a1 condition is satisfied; pivot = 1; i =0; b=1; since 0<=1, i evaluates to 1, j evaluates to 1, but since 1<1 is false, they dont get swapped; quicksort(a,0,1) and quicksort(a,1,1) are called. So Infinite loop. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't consider the case when `i == j` and also, as @MK said in a comment, the pivot should be a value and not an index (`pivot = (a1+b1)/2;` should be something like `pivot = a[(a1+b1)/2]`).

For example, if you start the array `a = {2, 45, 56, 3, 125}` (the array you indicated in a comment) your implementation could transform into `{2, 3, 45, 56, 125}` with `i = 2`, `j = 2`, and also `pivot = 2` (treated as an index). In this case the program would go into an infinite loop because it never enters the last `if` block.

If you change the inner if's condition to `i <= j` it should be correct.

In the end, applying also some minor optimizations, your code should look like the following:

```
void quicksort(int *a, int a1, int b1)
{
    if (b1 > a1)    // one less operation (subtraction) with respect to the original
    {
        int pivot = a[a1 + ((b1 - a1) / 2)];    // it is now a value and not an index. the index is calculated in this way to avoid an arithmetic overflow
        int i = a1;
        int j = b1;
        while (i <= j)
        {
            while (a[i] < pivot) //left to right
                i++;
            while (a[j] > pivot) //right to left
                j--;
            if (i <= j) // swapping
            {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        quicksort(a, a1, j);
        quicksort(a, i, b1); //recursive calls
    }
}
```

As a last optimization I would suggest to [optimize the tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons).

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: The first answer was slightly off track. Re-edited it and added some micro optimizations.